# highcharts a.onContainerClick is not a function

Tags: javascript, highcharts

We have attached our drill down event on bars and categories in highchart, and we are sending ajax call on every click event in chart. Charts are working fine but giving script error after getting render:

```
highcharts a.onContainerClick is not a function
```

Comment: While we are enabling debugger mode then this error is not coming

Comment: If you could provide a code sample or fiddle, that would be helpful in diagnosing this problem. What I've found in the past is that Highcharts can be fussy about link events within a chart, often leading to this exact error. I have a suggestion, but I'd like to see your code first to make sure it's helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed our app was having the same problem.
Found this:

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2775

> i used @larrydahooster's setTimeout to disrupt the sync flow and the
>   error has disappeared now. My react component with the chart was
>   re-rendering and so the original chart was gone when the
>   onContainerClick event was triggered.

We had code that would store the users option, and redraw the chart when they clicked a legend item. We did wrap the code in a setTimeout, and the error went away.